winpty running using cygwin on windows server 2016 - segmentation fault
I followed the guideline from https://github.com/rprichard/winpty to install winpty using cygwin.
After I make and make install it, I copied all the files under /bin to the /cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/
cd /home/appdump/shell/sa/windows/winpty-0.4.3-cygwin-2.8.0-x64/bin
cp -a * /cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/

Has anyone encountered this issue before?
but when I execute /usr/bin/winpty --version or any other command example /usr/bin/winpty /bin/bash, I encountered the error below:
dministrator@dep332-winweboversea01-50 /home/appdump
$ /usr/bin/winpty /bin/bash
Segmentation fault

I also already make sure the echo $PATH include /cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/ this path.
